# Problem to find the limit of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_0=a,$ $x_1=b$, and $x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{3}(x_n+2x_{n+1})$ for integers $n\ge 0.$ Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$.

Comment: Do you mean $$x_{n+2}=\frac13(x_n+2x_{n+1}),$$ or do you mean $$x_{n+2}=\frac1{3(x_n+2x_{n+1})},$$ instead?

Comment: I wanted to mean the first one.

Comment: I would write this as an iteration $z_n = A^n z_0$, where $z_n$ is the vector $(x_{n+1}, x_n)$ and $A$ is the matrix with components $(2/3, 1/3; 1, 0)$; is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: for the answer:this does not give no further information and give reason for existence of the limit.

Comment: Please help me for finding the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to picture what is going on, here. For brevity and simplicity, we will assume that $a<b.$ (The $a=b$ case is simplicity itself, and the $a>b$ case is just like the $a<b$ case, but with the jumps in the opposite direction at each stage.)

Let $d=|b-a|=b-a.$ To get from $x_0$ to $x_1$, we will jump right by $d$. Next, we'll jump $\frac13$ of the way toward $x_0$ from $x_1$--that is, jump by $\frac13d$ to the left--to get to $x_2$. Next, we'll jump $\frac13$ of the way toward $x_1$ from $x_2$--that is, jump by $\frac13\cdot\frac13d=\frac1{3^2}d$ to the right--to get to $x_3$. This pattern repeats. So, we start at $a,$ jump right by $d,$ left by $\frac{d}{3},$ right by $\frac{d}{3^2},$ left by $\frac{d}{3^3},$ right by $\frac{d}{3^4},$ and so on.

In general (even when $a\ge b$), we will see that for $n\ge 1,$ we have $$x_n=a+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(-\frac13\right)^k(b-a)=a+(b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(-\frac13\right)^k.$$ What do you know about geometric series (specifically, when they converge, and to what limits)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}$: it is $-\frac13 (x_{n+1} - x_n)$. So the consecutive differences decay as $3^{-n}$.

Consider $3 x_{n+2} + x_{n+1}$: it is $3 x_{n+1} + x_n$. An invariant! Therefore the limit is $(3 b + a)/4$, because if $x_{n+1} \approx x_n \approx x$ then $3 x_{n+1} + x_n \approx 4 x$.

Answer (score 1):

Do $x_n = \lambda^n$. However, $3\lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 1 = 0$ is characteristic equation. The roots $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = -1/3$. General solutions is 
$x_n = C_1 + C_2(-1/3)^n \ \to \ C_1$ if $n \to +\infty$. Know $x_0 \ \Rightarrow \ C_1$.